# Filtrado por fechas SQLite C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

Tengo una tabla en SQLite con varios campos entre ellos una fecha de tipo Text con el siguiente formato:

```
"2018-11-04 12:13:00"
```

Como SQLite no posee el campo Date ando en problemas para realizar consultas del tipo fechas mayores o menores a una que pase con el mismo formato ya que el la toma como un string, alguien podría indicarme si es posible realizar este tipo de consultas?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias darle un formato a la fecha usando algo como esto

```
var FechaInicio = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var FechaFin = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

using(var connection = new SQLiteConnection(cntnStr))
{
    connection.Open();

    string query = "select * from tabla where campoDate >= @FechaInicio and campoDate <= @FechaFin";
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FechaInicio", FechaInicio));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FechaFin", FechaFin));

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //resto codigo
}
```

si el formato necesita la hora podrias usar

```
var FechaInicio = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: De acuerdo en todo, pero yo, si sólo trabaja con fechas, añadiría la función `Date` a la consulta para obviar el elemento de la hora y que se comparen las fechas únicamente de esta manera: `SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE Date(campoDate) >= @FechaInicio`. De esta manera, si la fecha en la base de datos tiene hora, se ignora.